# matplotlib.pyplot plot() causes program to crash

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a plot that I update every minute and then save. It keeps causing my program to crash after 50-300 iterations.

How do I prevent that the program crashes?

code:

```
        fig = plt.figure(2)
        plt.cla()
        epochs = range(1, len(self.loss) + 1)
        plt.plot(epochs, np.array(self.loss),
                 label='%s ( "%f" )' % ("loss", min(self.loss)))
        plt.plot(epochs, np.array(self.val_loss),
                 label='%s ( "%f" )' % ("validation loss", min(self.val_loss)))
        plt.title("loss")
        plt.xlabel('Epochs')
        plt.ylabel('loss')
        self._save_plot_show_without_blocking(fig, "loss")
        plt.legend()
        fig.savefig(self.figure_save_path + '/%s.png' % name, bbox_inches='tight')
        plt.pause(3)
        plt.close()
```

Error message:

```
File "C:\Users\dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Comment: Are u sure that this fragment of code is executed in the main loop?

Comment: Try calling `plot.clf()` but are you sure that the problem isn't elsewhere?

Comment: the code is running as part of the main loop. As I understand it tkinter ( which matplotlib uses ) runs in a separate loop.

Comment: I am not 100% sure it's this part of the code, but I don't use any derivative of tkinter elsewhere to the best of my knowllege. And the apearance of the error is around the time in which that code runs ( unfortunatly it doesn't break even with debug).

Comment: I commented the above code to validate that it is causing the issues. The program doesn't crash when I omit it.